# Collect information from two tables in foreaches

Tags: php

I have the image product ID in one database table and the image Source in another table. These are all put into an order. There can be more than one image in a single order. I am trying to send each picture to Pwinty.

So for each image I need to make this:

```
$photo = $pwinty->addPhoto($order, "$size", "$source", "$qty", "ShrinkToFit");
// I have not got to the size and qty variable yet

// Because of that I have this instead
$photo = $pwinty->addPhoto($order, "4x6", "$source", "1", "ShrinkToFit");
```

Right now, because they are in multiple tables I have the following code: (which is not returning the photo array above at all.

```
// Get the customers pictures for this order 
foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM order_products WHERE order_id=$order_id") as $row)
$picture_info[] = $row;

if (count($picture_info) > 0):
    foreach ($picture_info as $row):

        $product_id = $row['product_id'];

        echo $product_id;

        foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id=$product_id") as $row)
        $picture_source[] = $row;

            foreach ($picture_source as $row):

                $source = $row['product_image'];

                echo $source;

                // add some photos
                $photo = $pwinty->addPhoto($order, "4x6", "$source", "1", "ShrinkToFit");


            endforeach; 

    endforeach;

endif;
```

What it is returning is:

```
14138646283376c471632817da60f95964cb2d57dc46.png
Array
(
[id] => 7776
[address1] => 2002 E Blain
[address2] => 
[postalOrZipCode] => 68460
[country] => United States
[addressTownOrCity] => Belvidear
[recipientName] => Joe Dohn
[textOnReverse] => Photos by AlphaHQ
[stateOrCounty] => Kansas
[status] => NotYetSubmitted
[payment] => 
[paymentUrl] => 
[photos] => Array
    (
    )

[documents] => Array
    (
    )

[stickers] => Array
    (
    )

    )
```

See how the image array is empty? What do I need to fix?

Comment: Just so everyone is clear.... It does not good to down vote a question without giving a reason. Plus everyone was a beginner once. Thanks :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with being a beginner, but it doesn't allow you to avoid rules or requirements, nor change the fact that people are entitled to their own reasons for downvoting. Where is your image Stored? What table? Can you get the image data without all the complicated foreach etc?

Answer (score -1):

Optimization Note: You are better off listing what you want from a select statement than saying SELECT *.  SQL will execute faster

Can you show us the output you get from all your echos?

Also when you echo things as a test it's good to put in some text describing what you are echoing so even if it's set to NULL you will see the text and now that variable is empty.

It appears that right now

```
foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id=$product_id") as $row)
```

Is not actually getting any rows.

A simple test you can do is

```
echo "My row is " + $row + "\n";
```

So you can see what rows you are actually getting.

Comment: If you cannot comment, just answer questions where it is an answer, help to improve edit questions which gets you rep. Everyone had to do it and it doesn't take long. The not being able to comment until 50 rep is there for a reason ;)

Comment: OK thanks.  I guess I can comment on my own posts.  *editing my answer*